# Not working Android SmatFox Server examples

Tags: android, smartfoxserver

I tried to compile this example on my computer, and all apps have errors like this :

```
04-17 18:01:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(271): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 18:01:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(271): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{sfs2x.example.android.tris/sfs2x.example.android.tris.Tris}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sfs2x.example.android.tris.Tris in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/sfs2x.example.android.tris-2.apk]
04-17 18:01:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(271):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
04-17 18:01:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(271):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
04-17 18:01:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(271):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
04-17 18:01:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(271):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
04-17 18:01:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(271):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-17 18:01:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(271):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-17 18:01:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(271):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
04-17 18:01:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(271):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 18:01:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(271):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-17 18:01:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(271):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
04-17 18:01:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(271):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
04-17 18:01:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(271):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-17 18:01:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(271): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sfs2x.example.android.tris.Tris in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/sfs2x.example.android.tris-2.apk]
04-17 18:01:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(271):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)    
04-17 18:01:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(271):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)    
04-17 18:01:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(271):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)    
04-17 18:01:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(271):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)    
04-17 18:01:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(271):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)    
04-17 18:01:18.493: E/AndroidRuntime(271):    ... 11 more
```

Download exaples from [HERE](http://docs2x.smartfoxserver.com/ExamplesAndroid/tris)

I have:

- Windows 7 X64, Eclipse and Android NDK last versions.
- Latest version of SmartFox server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the solution to my issue was this link:

http://android.foxykeep.com/dev/how-to-fix-the-classdefnotfounderror-with-adt-17

specifically this:

```
If you have references to jars that are not in the ‘libs’ folder, for example if you use ‘classpath variable’, you can resolve the NoClassDefFoundError issue with the new ADT 17 by exporting the references.

To export the references: simply go to “Properties > Java Build Path > Order and Export”, and check all the references you want exported.
```